# Writing data into database table issue

Tags: php, sql, drupal

I have function that has to write some data into database table, but after function complete, i dont see added info in my phpmyadmin. Here is code of what am i trying to run

```
function q_cart_add($node) {
    global $user;
    //drupal_set_title('Добавление товара в корзину');
    drupal_set_title('Товар добавлен в корзину');
    if (!user_access('add to cart'))
        return '<p>У вас не достаточно прав для добавления в корзину</p>';
    if ($node->type != 'kartochka')
        return '<p>В корзину можно положить только товар</p>';
    $added = false;
    if ($user->uid) {
        $added = db_result(db_query('SELECT `added` FROM {q_cart} WHERE `uid` = %d OR `nid` = %d', $user->uid, $node->nid));
        if (!$added) {
            db_query('INSERT INTO {q_cart} (`uid`, `nid`, `added`) VALUES (%d, %d, %d)', $user->uid, $node->nid, time());
        }
    } else {
        foreach (isset($_COOKIE['q_cart']) && ($cart = json_decode($_COOKIE['q_cart'])) ? $cart : array() as $item)
            if ($item->nid == $node->nid) {
                $added = true;
                break;
            }
        if (!$added) {
            $cart[] = array(
                'nid'   => $node->nid,
                'added' => time(),
            );
            setcookie('q_cart', json_encode($cart), strtotime('+1 week'), '/');
        }
    }
    //if (!$added) return '<p>Товар добавлен в корзину.</p>'.l('Корзина', 'cart', array('attributes' => array('target' => '_top', 'class' => 'button-link'))).'<a href="javascript://" onclick="parent.Lightbox.end(\'forceClose\');" class="button-link">Позже</a>';
    if (!$added) {
        drupal_add_js('$(document).ready(function(){parent.document.getElementById("bottomNavClose").style.display = "none";parent.document.getElementById("lightbox").style.top = "200px";});', 'inline');
        return l('Корзина', 'cart', array('attributes' => array('target' => '_top', 'class'  => 'button-link'))) .
                '<a href="/node/' . $node->nid . '" target ="_top" class="button-link">Позже</a>';
        //'<a href="javascript://" onclick="parent.Lightbox.end(\'forceClose\');" class="button-link">Позже</a>';
    } else {
        return '<p>Товар уже есть в вашей корзине.</p>';
    }
}
```

Comment: What does `db_query()` do? Give us *that* code, and an output of the query you're passing to it.

Comment: @Matt [`db_query()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21database.pgsql.inc/function/db_query/6) is a Drupal API function, it's not really feasible to post the full code here as there are a lot of different functions involved

Comment: @Clive thanks. I'm not a Drupal developer, so I wasn't sure. In that case it's very likely that it's the query itself that's the issue. @avdept, just `echo` the query to the screen and `exit()`;

Comment: Is it possible you're trying to do this as an anonymous user? `if ($user->uid)` will fail for anonymous users so the query would never run

Comment: No, i'm logged as root(uid = 1);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please change db_query to mysql_query and add or die(mysql_error()). It shoud explain why adding fails.

For example: mysql_query('INSERT INTO {q_cart} (`uid`, `nid`, `added`) VALUES ('.$user->uid.', '.$node->nid.', '.time().')') or die(mysql_error());

Comment: It actually passed, no error happened, aswell as didnt add info to database table

Comment: You should stop using `mysql_*` functions. They're being deprecated. Instead use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) (supported as of PHP 5.1) or [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) (supported as of PHP 4.1). If you're not sure which one to use, [read this SO article](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13569/mysqli-or-pdo-what-are-the-pros-and-cons).

Comment: To be honest, its not my code, its from some module that im using in my project.

Comment: In this case using mysql_query or die is the fastest way to solve the problem. It seems that this is problem with mysql syntax.

Comment: @mkey the fastest way to solve it is ***NOT*** to use bad practices. Just `echo` the query

Comment: something like this? 
     ``echo db_query('INSERT INTO {q_cart} (`uid`, `nid`, `added`) VALUES (%d, %d, %d)', $user->uid, $node->nid, time()) or die(mysql_error());``

Comment: To print this query just use printf('INSERT INTO {q_cart} (`uid`, `nid`, `added`) VALUES (%d, %d, %d)', $user->uid, $node->nid, time());

Comment: it gave me: ``INSERT INTO {q_cart} (`uid`, `nid`, `added`) VALUES (1, 760, 1344607784)``

Comment: SQL looks OK. Try this way:

`$insert = db_insert('q_cart')->fields(array('uid' => $user->uid,'nid' => $node->nid,'added' => time()));
  
  try
  {
   $insert_i = $insert->execute();
  }
  catch (PDOException $pe)
  {
   echo $pe->getMessage();
  }`

Comment: As you can read in the drupal documentation: Do not use this (db_query) function for INSERT, UPDATE, or DELETE queries. Those should be handled via db_insert(), db_update() and db_delete() respectively.